# Issues in installation of PHP in MacBook air M1 chip

Tags: php, mysql, apache, macos-big-sur, apple-m1

I recently bought a new MacBook Air M1 chipset. Now the issue that I am facing is that while I was trying to install PHP 7.4, Apache, MySQL, and PHPMyAdmin on the system it couldn't allow me to complete the installation process. As we all know that all this software is not currently providing support on the M1 chipset.

Is there any other alternative way to install this software with this chipset?

I have installed XAMPP server in my MacBook Air M1 but it is throwing me error Please check  [image]

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: maybe the error is come from your code. Please show some code

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest you go through [Is apple silicon ready?](https://isapplesiliconready.com/) first. Here You can get acknowledgement if your software is M1 optimized or not.

Also they have mentioned is the software support is available through Rosetta2 or not too.

For PHP, It's not advisable to upgrade the system-provided PHP, but it's also not necessary.

`brew link` can be used to decide *which* PHP is utilized. `brew link php@7.4` should do the trick; this can be also used to switch PHP versions around, i.e. `brew link php@8.0` will switch you over to that while leaving both versions installed and available directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing the software packages like MAMP or XAMPP (for Mac)

MAMP :
https://www.mamp.info

XAMPP :
https://www.apachefriends.org/download_success.html

I personally like MAMP pro, it is a paid software, but you can install a trial version, also there is a free version which is MAMP.

Comment: Does it provide support for M1 chipset In MacBook Air?

Comment: It has got nothing to do with your processor.. I have M1 Macbook Pro and it works fine

Comment: I have got above error @5eeker please check. how can I solve?

Comment: Your error is not clear, can you check on show details and post the error